# as if it is vs. as if it were vs. as if it was

Tags: grammar, usage

I learned from many sources that ***as if it were*** is accepted by all native English speakers. And ***as if it was*** is widely used, especially informally. But is the simple present indicative accepted  as well in this context? That is, can ***as if it is*** be used in hypothetical situations?

> When driving a car, flow is the feeling of oneness with the machine,
> which performs ***as if it were*** an extension of the body. When
> surfing on the Internet, it is the seamless sequence of responses
> facilitated by machine interactivity, being intrinsically enjoyable
> and accompanied by loss of self-consciousness.

[Psychoanalytic Accounts of Consuming Desire: Hearts of Darkness](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=dFjmDKmW52AC&pg=PA56&lpg=PA56&dq=When%20driving%20a%20car,%20flow%20is%20the%20feeling%20of%20oneness%20with%20the%20machine,%20which%20performs%20as%20if%20it%20were%20an%20extension%20of%20the%20body.&source=bl&ots=8vP0D3516Z&sig=ACfU3U2Uzf82Ipoz-2IP5okBIB8toANGEw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjqLzOprj4AhWOy4sBHb26CEYQ6AF6BAgcEAM#v=onepage&q=When%20driving%20a%20car%2C%20flow%20is%20the%20feeling%20of%20oneness%20with%20the%20machine%2C%20which%20performs%20as%20if%20it%20were%20an%20extension%20of%20the%20body.&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

"If it were" or "If it was" can be used to give a hypothetical condition.  It's not actually true that the car is a part, or an extension, of your body, but *hypothetically* if it was an extension, you would get the same feeling of flow.

"If it is" could be used to give a condition that could (perhaps in the future) be true. But this is not the intended meaning here.